# 222 x 555 = hill

Tags: mathematics

When I multiply numbers that contain twos and fives, I get a number, the digits in which first increase and then decrease, for example:

```
22 x 55 = 1210
222 x 555 = 123210
2222 x 5555 = 12343210
22222 x 55555 = 1234543210
```

My father once showed me this property and I still think why this is happening.

Is there a simple mathematical explanation?

Comment: Why ask here? Are aware of https://math.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: No problem, and glad that you took it as meant :-) You seem new here, and there are many, many, many sites. It is not always clear which is best. When I get bored, I explore [them all](https://stackexchange.com/sites). I especially like looking at [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/), which is for proposing new sites. Welcome aboard (a little late for me to say so), have fun, learn, and help others :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple mathematical explanation.

First of all, factor out the 2 and the 5, which just give you a 0 on the end of the number. So what we have to explain is e.g. that 1111x1111=1234321.

There are a few ways to see why this works. Here's one. Think about doing the multiplication the way you learned to at school:

```
   1111
  1111
 1111
1111
-------
```

and notice that when you do the final addition step here you're adding **one** 1 for the leftmost digit, then **two** for the next digit, then **three**, then **four**, then **three**, then **two**, then **one** for the rightmost digit.

There's a higher-brow way of expressing this, thinking about what happens when you multiply out $(10^k+10^{k-1}+\cdots+10^0)^2$, but it's really just the same observation fancied-up a bit. There might be a fancier way still involving the observation that e.g. 1111=9999/9=(10000-1)/9; I can see how to make that give you the "ascending" part of the hill, but the other half isn't so clear.

Of course all this breaks down a little when you start dealing with numbers of more than 9 digits.

Exercise for the reader: what about products like 111x11111?